# Storyboard - Creating two different Views in storyboard for the same ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I m new in ios development. I m using storyboard for my application, i am creating a two UIView in one UIViewController, in my first view i have one button, i want to when i click on button, picker view(second View) will display that View have one picker, one done and one cancel button.

Comment: refer this [http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)[http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

Comment: i am using this link but it is working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557362/multiple-views-in-xcode-storyboard-view-controller-one-of-them-wont-appear-in

Comment: use view1.hidden=YES; and view2.hidden=NO; on your button action.

Comment: Thanks for answer Ashini...could you share any example for it.

Comment: wait i will post the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIView *view1;
IBOutlet UIView *view2;
}
@end
ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
view2.hidden=YES;} //initially set view2 as hidden.



//IBAction Methods
- (IBAction)Go_To_SecondView:(id)sender {
view1.hidden=YES;
view2.hidden=NO;}


 - (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
//your code

}
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {

//your code
}
```

Your view Controller Scene should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Add two views and add the buttons and pickerview .
- Use the hidden property set to hidden for second view when view appears.
- On button click make the second view appear using `hidden` set to no and `bringToFront` methods